# How do I make a random video play on pageload?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a random video player in html/js.
It is supposed to play a different video on pageload and as soon as one video is over, it should play another one.

HTML

```
<video width="320" height="240" autoplay>
    <source src="abcdefg.com/example1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="abcdefg.com/example2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

JS

```
<script>

var videos = [
    [{type:'mp4', 'src':'abcdefg.com/example1.mp4'}],
    [{type:'mp4', 'src':'abcdefg.com/example2.mp4'}],  
];


$(function() {
    var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*videos.length);
    $(this).find('source').each(function(index){ 
          videoSrc = videos[number][index].src;
          $(this).attr('src', videoSrc);
          $('video').load();
          $('video').play();
        });
});

</script>
```

However, my current code plays the same video every page reload and as soon as it's over, nothing happens.

How do I need to optimize my code so it automatically plays a different video on every pageload + when the previous video is over?

Comment: What are you doing to get a new video once the first one is over?

Comment: @JensW I only have the code above. I thought it would automatically load a new one because it's checking for it's length.

Comment: I think the function is only executed once on page load.

Comment: So how do I make it so it executes it on pageload + when the previous video is over?

Comment: are u getting any  console error?

Comment: are u calling jQuery script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,I have added an event listener to video end property and called the newvideo() function ,so that every time the video finishes a new random video is loaded from array.I could'nt find more video urls ,you can test and let me know if it works for you.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var videos = [
    [{type:'mp4', 'src':'http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4'}],
    [{type:'mp4', 'src':'http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4'}],
    [{type:'mp4', 'src':'http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4'}]
];

// selecting random item from array,you can make your own
var randomitem = videos[Math.floor(Math.random()*videos.length)];

// This function adds a new video source (dynamic) in the video html tag

function videoadd(element, src, type) {
    var source = document.createElement('source');

    source.src = src;
    source.type = type;
   element.appendChild(source);
}
// this function fires the video for particular video tag

function newvideo(src)
{
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
videoadd(vid,src ,'video/ogg');
vid.autoplay = true;
vid.load();
//vid.play();
}
// function call
newvideo(randomitem[0].src)

// Added an event listener so that everytime the video finishes ,a new video is loaded from array
document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended',handler,false);

function handler(e)
{
newvideo(randomitem[0].src)

}
  

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video width="320" height="240" autoplay id="myVideo">
  
</video>
```

Comment: This code works. Thank you for your contribution!
There is just one more problem.  Sometimes, it doesent play a video. There is just a blackscreen, but as soon as I reload the page it plays a video.

Comment: Yes,I know that may be some issue with video urls. Do accept the answer if it worked for you Thanks

Comment: The code works fine except after finishing the initial video. From there it will just play the randomly picked video on pageload over and over ingoring the other video sources. According to the markup it will add an undefined source to the existing one each time the video has ended.