# I need my webpage to play random videos but the JS keeps repeating the same random video unless I refresh webpage

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, arraylist, random

The HTML section loops but repeatedly plays the same randomly selected video selected by the JS. If I refresh the html it will play a different video. I would like it to choose a different random video after each delayms expires. I apologize, I am kind of new to programming and my terminology is off.

```
//HTML
{url:randvideo1, delayms:10000},

//video arrays found in JS

var videoArray1 = [
"v/video01.mp4",
"v/video02.mp4",
"v/video03.mp4",
"v/video04.mp4"
];

var randvideo1 = videoArray1[Math.floor(Math.random()*videoArray1.length)];
```

Comment: This code is not enough to determine the problem. Post the part of your code that deals with starting/switching videos

Comment: A minimal example of this could be switching anything, it wouldn't have to be videos, so you could probably build your example in the SO javascript snippet tool

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a random video play on pageload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56489545/how-do-i-make-a-random-video-play-on-pageload)

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) which calls a function every given amount of time.

```js
const delay = 3000;

var videoArray1 = [
  "v/video01.mp4",
  "v/video02.mp4",
  "v/video03.mp4",
  "v/video04.mp4"
];

function playVideo() {
  var randvideo1 = videoArray1[Math.floor(Math.random() * videoArray1.length)];
  
  console.log(`Playing video ${randvideo1} for ${delay / 1000} seconds...`)
  
  /* 
    The rest of your code to set the new video source in the html.
  */
}

setInterval(playVideo, delay);
```